# Azure function worker isolated process .NET 6 - work with servicebus and servicebus trigger

Tags: azure-functions, azureservicebus, .net-6.0, azure-servicebus-topics, dotnet-isolated

I'm working with Azure Function isolated process .net 6.

I have an issue to work with the service bus and service bus trigger.

If in-process I will declare like this

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = null)]HttpRequest req, ILogger log, ExecutionContext context,
    [ServiceBus("mail-sender", Connection = "ServiceBusConnection")] IAsyncCollector<dynamic> outgoingMessage)
{
    ... outgoingMessage.Send(mymessage);...
}
```

And then I will have another service bus trigger azure function to process the message like this

```
   public void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("mail-sender", Connection = "ServiceBusConnection")]string myQueueItem, ILogger log)
        {
            try
            {
                var mailHost = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MAIL_HOST") ?? "smtp.sendgrid.net";
                var mailPort = Convert.ToInt32(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MAIL_PORT") ?? "587");
                var mailUsername = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MAIL_USERNAME") ?? "apikey";
                var mailPassword = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MAIL_PASSWORD") ?? "8755faf7-78c9-4389-b3a5-f1578953bc00";
                var ssl = Convert.ToBoolean(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MAIL_SSL") ?? "false");

                using (var mailHelpers = new MailHelpers(mailHost, mailPort, mailUsername, mailPassword, ssl))
                {
                    var mail = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MailViewModel>(myQueueItem);
                    mailHelpers.Send(mail);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.LogError(ex, "Error during sending email.");
            }
        }
```

How can I achieve that in the azure function isolated process?

Please help me to give example detail and the package's dependencies if any.

Many thanks

===========================

BTW, I have declare TimerTrigger azure function, it uses https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Timer
It can trigger the task to run, but I cannot debug it? I'm not sure why?

```
        public async Task<DispatchedMessages> Run([TimerTrigger("* * * * * *")] MyInfo myTimer)
        {
            try
            {...}
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand your question, the flow will look like something like this:

1. post to Httptrigger
2. the HttpTrigger will queue a message in some service bus queue (for detail about how to post a message to the queue see [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dotnet-get-started-with-queues#add-code-to-send-messages-to-the-queue)) Here is how you can send a message to a service bus queue:

```cs
using Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus;

public class ServiceBusAdapter
    {
        private readonly ServiceBusClient _client;

        public ServiceBusAdapter(ServiceBusClient client)
        {
            _client = client;
        }

        public async Task SendMessage(string queueName, BinaryData body, string? messageId = null)
        {
            ServiceBusMessage sbMessage = CreateServiceBusMessage(body, messageId);
            await using ServiceBusSender sender = _client.CreateSender(queueName);

            try
            {
                await sender.SendMessageAsync(CreateServiceBusMessage(body, messageId));
            }
            catch (ServiceBusException e) when (e.IsTransient)
            {
                throw new SomeCustomException(e.Message, e);
            }
        }

        public async Task SendMessages(string queueName, IEnumerable<Message> messages)
        {
            Queue<ServiceBusMessage> sbMessages = new(messages.Select(m => CreateServiceBusMessage(m.Body, m.MessageId)));
            await using ServiceBusSender sender = _client.CreateSender(queueName);

            // While all messages are not sent to the Service Bus queue
            while (sbMessages.Count > 0)
            {
                // Start a new batch
                using ServiceBusMessageBatch messageBatch = await sender.CreateMessageBatchAsync();

                // Add the first message to the batch
                if (messageBatch.TryAddMessage(sbMessages.Peek()))
                {
                    // Dequeue the message from the .NET queue once the message is added to the batch
                    sbMessages.Dequeue();
                }
                else
                {
                    // If the first message can't fit, then it is too large for the batch.
                    // Try to send it anyway so that we get a proper service bus exception.
                    await sender.SendMessageAsync(sbMessages.Dequeue());
                    continue;
                }

                // Add as many messages as possible to the current batch
                while (sbMessages.Count > 0 && messageBatch.TryAddMessage(sbMessages.Peek()))
                {
                    // Dequeue the message from the .NET queue as it has been added to the batch
                    sbMessages.Dequeue();
                }

                try
                {
                    // Now, send the batch
                    await sender.SendMessagesAsync(messageBatch);
                }
                catch (ServiceBusException e) when (e.IsTransient)
                {
                    throw new SomeCustomException(e.Message, e);
                }

                // If there are any remaining messages in the .NET queue, the while loop repeats
            }
        }

        private static ServiceBusMessage CreateServiceBusMessage(BinaryData body, string? messageId)
        {
            var message = new ServiceBusMessage(body);

            if (messageId is not null)
            {
                // Service Bus (Standard and Premium SKU but not Basic) finds
                // duplicates by this MessageId
                message.MessageId = messageId;
            }

            return message;
        }
    }
```

3. once the message is queued the service bus will notify the ServiceBusTrigger that is configured and listening to that queue.

Here is an example of a ServiceBusTrigger in .net 6 isolated functions:

```cs
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace Functions.Sample
{
    public class SampleServiceBusTrigger
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;
        private const string QueueName = "My.Sample.Queue.Name";

        private readonly ISomeHandler _someHandler;

        public SampleServiceBusTrigger(
            ILoggerFactory loggerFactory,
            ISomeHandler someHandler)
        {
            _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<SampleServiceBusTrigger>();
            _someHandler = someHandler;
        }

        [Function(nameof(SampleServiceBusTrigger))]
        public async Task RunAsync(
            [ServiceBusTrigger(QueueName)] MyObject outMessage)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Triggered...");
            await _someHandler.Execute(outMessage);
            _logger.LogInformation("Completed.");
        }
    }
}
```

You will also need to add these configs to your `local.settings.json` for local development:

```
"FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated",
"AzureWebJobsServiceBus": "<YOUR SB CONNECTION STRING>",
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So how do you send messages to servicebus in isolated process? @Aram B?

Comment: @jack.pop I will update my answer :)

Comment: Thanks, @Aram B. It looks like the stuff I need—Let me try with your suggestion.

Comment: Hi @Aram B the ServiceBusTrigger is not triggered although the message is already in the queue.  Have you encountered the issue before? Please advise.

Comment: hard to say, do you get any errors? Are the service started correctly? Ensure the queue name and such settings are setup correctly everywhere. Have you changes the queue name in the ServiceBusTrigger class?

Comment: Hi @Aram B, I manage to solve the issue. The issue was caused by authentication middleware and authorization middleware which I self-implemented. I throw exception/error before going through the function execution. Thanks again. I will mark your reply as a solution.