# Upgrading In-Process Azure Function with ServiceBusmessage

Tags: c#, azure-functions, .net-7.0

We want to upgrade an existing In-Process Azure Function to .NET 7.0, since we want to migrate the dependencies to .NET 7.0 too. This Azure Function uses the `ServiceBusReceivedMessage` and its metadata, which does not seem to be supported in Isolated Azure Functions.

Creating a wrapper JSON object which contains the metadata of the message is not an option just in order to upgrade to .NET 7.0 (then we would rather stay .NET 6.0 for now).

Do we have to wait for Microsoft to either support `ServiceBusReceivedMessage` in isolated Azure Function or support .NET 7.0 for in-process Azure Functions, or do I miss something?

It is a bit sad that only due to the fact that we have an Azure Function we cannot upgrade our entire solution to .NET 7.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- AFAIK, We have to wait for update of `ServiceBusReceivedMessage` in .NET 7 both in-process and Isolated Worker process.
- Because `ServiceBusReceivedMessage` is part of `Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus` Package that is available up to .NET 6 In-Process Version as shown [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus#supportedframeworks-body-tab).

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7AOVU.png]

- Here is an [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72782038/azure-function-worker-isolated-process-net-6-work-with-servicebus-and-service) that show how to use the Service Bus Message Class in .NET 6 Isolated Azure Functions.
- As .NET 7 Isolated Process came recently (Nov 1st Week) - to know the update of `ServiceBusReceivedMessage` in .NET 7, please raise the ticket in [Azure-sdk-for-net](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/new?title=&body=%0A%0A%5BEnter%20feedback%20here%5D%0A%0A%0A---%0A%23%23%23%23%20Document%20Details%0A%0A%E2%9A%A0%20*Do%20not%20edit%20this%20section.%20It%20is%20required%20for%20learn.microsoft.com%20%E2%9E%9F%20GitHub%20issue%20linking.*%0A%0A*%20ID%3A%20187cbbd5-ed7e-695d-b8b2-843a5f9578f3%0A*%20Version%20Independent%20ID%3A%20d91f85e9-f44f-ebe9-3cc4-bb1610b6104f%0A*%20Content%3A%20%5BServiceBusReceivedMessage%20Class%20(Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus)%20-%20Azure%20for%20.NET%20Developers%5D(https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fdotnet%2Fapi%2Fazure.messaging.servicebus.servicebusreceivedmessage%3Fview%3Dazure-dotnet)%0A*%20Content%20Source%3A%20%5Bxml%2FAzure.Messaging.ServiceBus%2FServiceBusReceivedMessage.xml%5D(https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2FAzure%2Fazure-docs-sdk-dotnet%2Fblob%2Fmaster%2Fxml%2FAzure.Messaging.ServiceBus%2FServiceBusReceivedMessage.xml)%0A*%20Service%3A%20**azure**%0A*%20GitHub%20Login%3A%20%40rloutlaw%0A*%20Microsoft%20Alias%3A%20**routlaw**) GitHub Repository.